# Is there a way to disable the 'All' option for pageSize in Kendo UI Vue Grid?

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui

I need help getting rid of the all option in the kendo grid page size dropdown.
[Example is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqF5h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the document you can set the **:pageable** to reflect what you want to configure as far as pageSizes go.  **pageable** can have a property that is **pageSizes** which is either **true** or an array of pageSizes (numbers).

Documentation:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/api/GridProps/#toc-pagesize